# Internalizing 'topology on a set'

Tags: ct.category-theory, internalization

In any topos $\mathcal{S}$, we have the ability to speak about [power objects](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/power+object) $\mathcal{P}(X)$ of objects $X\in\mathcal{S}$. We can then define an internal [closure operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_operator) as an arrow ${\sf cl}:\mathcal{P}(X)\to\mathcal{P}(X)$ satisfying some conditions on subobjects of $X$, and begin to do some 'topology on objects' internally. This is justified by the fact that taking $\mathcal{S}={\bf Set}$ yields the standard definition of a closure operator.

OTOH in any category $\mathcal{C}$ with pullbacks, we can define the [subobject fibration](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/codomain+fibration#the_subobject_fibration) ${\sf cod}:{\sf Sub}(\mathcal{C})\to\mathcal{C}$ as the [fibered skeleton](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/skeleton#skeleton_of_a_fibered_category) of the monomorphism fibration, then treat the fiber ${\sf Sub}(\mathcal{C})_X$ of an object $X\in\mathcal{C}$ as a power-category of $X$. A closure operator is then an idempotent [monad](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/monad) on ${\sf Sub}(\mathcal{C})_X$ -- this is justified again by the fact that taking $\mathcal{C}={\bf Set}$ yields ${\sf Sub}({\bf Set})_X\cong\mathcal{P}(X)$ (as posets) and the standard definition of a closure operator.

> Is there any relationship between these two approaches? Are they equivalent in a topos?

If there is any relationship between Grothendieck topologies and these approaches, like considering a Grothendieck topology on the fiber ${\sf Sub}(\mathcal{C})_X$ as a topology on $X$, I'd be interested to hear about it. I'm not too familiar with Grothendieck topologies though, and the discussion on the [nlab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Grothendieck+topology#historical_note_on_terminology) led me to believe that Grothendieck topologies relate to their underlying category in a different way than a topology relates to its underlying set. Any pointers are appreciated.

---

In any [geometric category](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/geometric+category) $\mathcal{C}$ it seems like we could also define a topology on $X\in\mathcal{C}$ to be a subcategory $\mathcal{T}$ of the power-category ${\sf Sub}(\mathcal{C})_X$ which is closed under small unions and finite pullbacks. This definition agrees with the standard definition of a topology on $X$ when realized in ${\bf Set}$, and feels the closest to 'a collection of subsets closed under arbitrary unions and finite intersections'.

> Is this definition equivalent to the above ones when working in a category with sufficient structure to compare the three approaches?

Comment: I think more work has been done on internal locales ("point-free topological spaces") than internal topological spaces.

Comment: Further to @ZhenLin's comment, internal locales are better behaved. See, for example, Michael Fourman and Martin Hyland. Sheaf models for analysis. In Michael Fourman, Chris
Mulvey, and Dana Scott, editors, Applications of Sheaves, number 753 in Lecture Notes in
Mathematics. Springer-Verlag, 1979.

Comment: @ZhenLin I have a passing familiarity with locales, but I've never actually sat down with them and done any computing. Topological spaces on the other hand I have a good handle on conceptually and computationally, so if possible I'd like to see how these more familiar notions change when internalized.

Comment: @PaulTaylor Thank you for the reference, I'll check it out.